# Remove child elements from Taxonomy List Exposed Filters

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, views

I have a view with (Taxonomy Reference Field) as Exposed Filter, The vocabulary contain parent terms and some child terms, I want to see the first level terms only and remove any children if any.

Currently It look like this

[image: Exposed Filter with Childes]

I want to remove the Keyboard Type 1, Type 2 and so on.

I was thinking of using a `hook_form_alter`, but not sure about the exact usage to remove any child term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution which I think is quite a bit simpler. Simply remove the entries from the form if they start with a '-'. Note that you must have the 'Show hierarchy in dropdown' option selected for the children to begin with a '-' hyphen.

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-[your-view-here]') {

    foreach ($form['tid']['#options'] as $term_key => $term) {

      // Check if this isn't the 'ANY' option
      if($term_key !== 'All') {
        // Check if this is a child by looking for '-' as first char in string
        $term_value = reset($term->option);
        if($term_value[0] == '-') {
          unset($form['tid']['#options'][$term_key]);
        }
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I did the same, but I forgot to add the answer myself. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but you can use **hook_form_alter** as you stated.

```
$localities = get_all_localities($term_id);
$localities_tids = array();

foreach ($localities as $tid => $name){
    $localities_tids[] = $tid;
}

//alter the available options in the exposed filters
foreach ($form['term_node_tid_depth_i18n']['#options'] as $tid => $term){
    if ( !in_array($tid, $localities_tids) ){
        if ( $tid != 0 && !empty($tid) ) {
            unset($form['term_node_tid_depth_i18n']['#options'][$tid]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I get all the localities (child elements) with parent **$term_id**, after that just compare the new tid's list with the id present on the form element and remove what u don't need using **unset()**

Will also leave you my example to get the child localities from the region parent id ($term_id).

```
function get_all_localities($regiao_selecionada) {
    $lang_code = get_site_lang();
    $loc_list = array();

    if ( !empty( $regiao_selecionada ) && $regiao_selecionada != '0' ) {
        $locs = db_query("
            SELECT td.tid, 
            COALESCE((SELECT lt.translation FROM locales_source ls, locales_target lt WHERE ls.lid = lt.lid AND ls.context LIKE CONCAT('term:',td.tid,':name') AND lt.language LIKE '$lang_code' LIMIT 1), td.name) as 'name', th.*  
            FROM taxonomy_term_data td, taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
            WHERE th.tid = td.tid AND td.vid = 5 AND th.parent = $regiao_selecionada AND td.name <> 'Foreign' AND td.name <> 'Nenhuma' AND td.tid NOT IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_hierarchy where parent IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_data td where td.name = 'Foreign' OR td.name = 'Nenhuma'))
            ORDER BY td.name ASC
        ");
    } else {
        $locs = db_query("
            SELECT td.tid, 
            COALESCE((SELECT lt.translation FROM locales_source ls, locales_target lt WHERE ls.lid = lt.lid AND ls.context LIKE CONCAT('term:',td.tid,':name') AND lt.language LIKE '$lang_code' LIMIT 1), td.name) as 'name', th.*  
            FROM taxonomy_term_data td, taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
            WHERE th.tid = td.tid AND td.vid = 5 AND th.parent <> 0 AND td.name <> 'Foreign' AND td.name <> 'Nenhuma' AND td.tid NOT IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_hierarchy where parent IN (select tid from taxonomy_term_data td where td.name = 'Foreign' OR td.name = 'Nenhuma'))
            ORDER BY td.name ASC
        ");

    }


    foreach ($locs as $id => $loc) {
        $loc_list[$loc->tid] = $loc->name;
    }

    return $loc_list;
}
```

Hope this can help you out.