# Trying to remove options form an exposed filter

Tags: theming, views

In drupal 7, I'm trying to remove an exposed taxonomy filter. This taxonomy filter has a depth of 2. I'm only trying to expose the parent item.

As a quick fix I'm trying (poorly) to remove them with the following theme function below.

```
<?php
function theme_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {

    //  views-exposed-form-instructor-profile-list-page
    switch($vars['form']['#id']) {

        // instructor profile       
        case 'views-exposed-form-instructor-profile-list-page':
            foreach ($vars['form']['term_node_tid_depth']['#options'] as $option) { 
                foreach ($option->option as $key=>$v) {
                        if (stristr($v, '-')) {
                            print $v . '<br>';
                            $vars['form']['term_node_tid_depth']['#options']['option'][$key] = 'FILTERED';
                        }
                }
            }           

            print_r($vars['form']['term_node_tid_depth']['#options']['option']);
            break;

        // do nothing
        default:



    }
}
```

In the end I'm trying to figure out what exactly to `unset()` any option that begins with '`- child item`'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead try the following it will help you by using `hook_form_alter()`

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-[your-view-here]') {

    foreach ($form['tid']['#options'] as $term_key => $term) {

      // Check if this isn't the 'ANY' option
      if($term_key !== 'All') {
        // Check if this is a child by looking for '-' as first char in string
        $term_value = reset($term->option);
        if($term_value[0] == '-') {
          unset($form['tid']['#options'][$term_key]);
        }
      }

    }

  }

}
```

taken from the [source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78574/remove-child-elements-from-taxonomy-list-exposed-filters)